# How to add custom filter in salesforce views

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, customsetting, list-view, filters

I have created a custom object in my org and showing a custom list view for that object. Salesforce provides filter option but it contains 2-3 steps, so I want to add a drop-down to filter the results and also if possible I want to get results of a particular time.
Adding the screenshot of view for reference, suppose I want to filter results on basis of grade and also in the range of registration date.[image: custom object list view]

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter icon (funnel) at extreme right and clicking on the icon, you can add custom filter like this.

[image: filter]

Comment: Hi Santanu,
Thank you for your response, but I am aware of this filter option, I want to add a drop-down at top of the page(near 'ALL' option) so that user can filter results on the basis of that selected value.